# The terms have been agreed. vs. The terms have been agreed to

Tags: word-usage, verbs, verb-usage

> The terms have been agreed.

vs.

> The terms have been agreed to.

The verb 'agree' is used as 'transitive or intransitive'.

I wonder which sentence is more common: with 'to' or without 'to' in case of the example sentence

Answer (score 1):

My take on it would be that

> The terms have been agreed [upon]

means that the parties have discussed the terms among themselves, and

> The terms have been agreed to

suggests that one side has agreed to accept the terms offered by the other.